# inclusion of von Neumann algebras implies reversing inequality of its modular operators

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, physics

I'm working with von Neumann algebras and I stumbled with this statement in a work of Borchers (1999)

> Since $\mathcal N \subseteq \mathcal M$, it follows by standard arguments that $\Delta_{\mathcal N} \ge \Delta_{\mathcal M}$

where we must think $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ as concrete von Neumann algebras over the same Hilbert space, and $\Delta_\mathcal{M}$ is the modular operator associated to $\mathcal{M}$ and similarly for $\Delta_\mathcal{N}$.

I suppose there is something I'm not catching because assuming $\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathcal{M}$,  I could only arrive to $S_{\mathcal{M}}(x)=S_\mathcal{N}(x)$ for $x\in \operatorname{Dom}(S_\mathcal{N})$ (to do that I assume there is a cyclic and separating vector for $\mathcal{N}$) where $S_R$ denotes the Tomita–Takesaki operator of the algebra $R$. This implies $\Delta_\mathcal{M}(x)=\Delta_\mathcal{N}(x)$, for $x\in \operatorname{Dom}(\Delta_\mathcal{N})$.

However, I couldn't find the proof of Borchers's assertion.

Comment: What is the work of Borchers?

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown by using the "characteristics matrix" of unbounded operators (see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-31/issue-1/Reduction-theory-for-unbounded-closed-operators-in-Hilbert-space/10.1215/S0012-7094-64-03103-5.short)). For an unbounded operator $X$, we write the projection $\mathcal{P}$ onto the closed subspace $\mathcal{H} \oplus \mathcal{H}$ generated by the graph using a two-by-two matrix $p_{i,k}$
$$p^*_{i,k} = p_{j,k}$$
where the following map holds
$$X \colon p_{1,1}\psi + p_{1,2} \phi \rightarrow p_{2,1}\psi + p_{2,2} \phi,\quad \psi,\phi \in \mathcal{H}$$
so one finds that the inverse of $p_{1,1}$ is given by
$$p_{1,1} = (1+XX^*)^{-1}$$
and for an extension of $X$, which we call $Y$, we have $\mathcal{P}(Y) \geq \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then one sees that
$$(1+YY^*)^{-1} \geq (1+XX^*)^{-1}$$

Now for the inclusion of von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{M}$, we do the same thing. Since now $X$ is an anti-linear operator (and thus $p_{1,2}$ and $p_{2,1}$ are anti-linear), the second Hilbert space must be replaced by complex conjugate Hilbert space. We get the following
$$(1+\Delta_{\mathcal{M}}^*)^{-1} \geq (1+\Delta_{\mathcal{N}}^*)^{-1}$$
which is
$$\Delta_{\mathcal{N}} \geq \Delta_{\mathcal{M}}$$